# Using $_GET to create multiple pages automaticly with a loop

Tags: php, html

please look the following code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['picture'] == 1) {
    echo "<img src=\"1.jpg\" />";
} else if ($_GET['picture'] == 2) {
    echo "<img src=\"2.jpg\" />";
} else if ($_GET['picture'] == 3) {
    echo "<img src=\"3.jpg\" />";
}
?>
```

Now, when I click a link like index.php?picture=1, the picture 1.jpg will appear. But, when I have a thousand of these, I don't want to create every If statement myself: so how to I loop through this? How can I create a loop so these are automatically created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the value inside of the echo'd string. Just check to make sure its less than your maximum (1000 or whatever):

```
$picture = intval($_GET['picture']);
if (picture > 0 && $picture < maximum) {
  echo "<img src=\"{$picture}.jpg\" />";
}
```

Comment: You may want to escape the GET parameter first.

Comment: @Thilo `intval` should be enough in this case (it wont allow `../` etc)

Comment: @Frank: if you not sure that `$_GET['picture']` is not `"500f**kingstring"` you should use `intval()` or `ctype_digit()`

Comment: @Matt Edit overlap :) intval wasn't there when I commented.

Comment: Thank you guys. My final code is:                                   $picture = intval(mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['picture']));
if ($picture > 0 && $picture < 100) {
  echo "<img src=\"{$picture}.jpg\" />";
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, make sure to stereotype the $_GET value as an integer or you can have some serious XSS problems.

```
<?php
$picnum=(int)$_GET['picture']; // make sure the value is a number to avoid XSS
echo "<img src='".$picnum.".jpg' />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$picture = isset($_GET['picture']) ? (int)$_GET['picture'] : 0;
if($picture)
    echo '<img src="'.$picture.'.jpg" />';
```